# How to get git notes from github API?

Tags: git, github-api

I'm trying to get the notes on a specific commit using Github API.

I added notes on the commit using `git notes append`, and I also pushed the notes to Github using `git push origin refs/notes/*`.

I can't seem to find a way to get the notes from the Github API.

Comment: Git notes are saved to and read from `refs/notes/commits` by default. I think you can retrieve notes by some reference related APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the list refs API to list all refs, including notes, and then use the GET ref API to retrieve the specific ref.

See list API documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#list-matching-references
See the GET ref API docs: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#get-a-reference

To be honest, I haven’t tried it myself. But they explicitly mention that calling the LIST api with an empty :ref parameter will return the notes ref as well.

Comment: notes ref is not enough, not sure how to get a note for a specific commit from notes ref

Comment: @Barnash Why not use this and then find the note which belongs to the commit locally?

Comment: Get a ref by commit SHA doesn't seem to work today. e.g. https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/ref/heads/master and try replace `heads/master` with sha